# What is the difference between лодыжка and щиколотка as a translation of "ankle"?

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление, выбор-слова, одним-словом, синонимы

**TL/DR:**

What is the difference between *щиколотка* and *лодыжка*, and which one is a better suited translation for "Ankle zips with reflective detailing"?

**Background**

As a personal vocabulary exercise, I decided to translate the English descriptions in a clothing magazine into Russian. I'm using Yandex translate to guide me through the process, and I've noticed that sometimes it'll provide two different translations depending on whether I include closing punctuation with the English input.

In the magazine, a description at the bottom of a pair of athletic leggings reads, **"Ankle zips with reflective detailing"**. Aside from "with", I'm not familiar with any of these words in Russian, so I typed the entire phrase into the translator, and, yes, received two different translations.

*Detailed Question:* The two translations I received are:

- **Молнии на щиколотках со светоотражающими деталями**
- **Лодыжки молнии с отражающей отделкой**

After some research, I understand that both **"лодыжка"** and **"щиколотка"** are related to the word **"ankle"**, but I can't find a clear difference between the words, nor can I decipher which word would fit in the description I'm attempting to translate.

I also can't figure out why the word order and phrasing with the word **"лодыжка"** would be **"Лодыжки молнии"**, but the word order and phrasing with the word **"щиколотка"** would be **"Молнии на щиколотках"**.

The translations also provide two different translations for "reflective" and "detailing", although I think I understand the difference. From what I gather, **"светоотражающий"** refers more to a reflective surface, while **"отражающий"** refers more to the concept of mentally reflecting on, or looking back at, something, and **"деталь"** in this context is more like the little details on the surface of clothing, while **"отделка"** is more like the detailed "finish" or "trim" around the edges. However, I'm not positive about these assessments.

Comment: Your question might get closed by moderators because generally asking for translation is off-topic here. But let's hope it won't)) You can throw away the second translation straight away - it's total rubbish, doesn't make any sense in Russian. *Лодыжки молнии...* translates back as *Ankles of a zip...* or *Zip's ankles...*, whatever you prefer :)

Comment: I'm afraid you need to study some basic Russian grammar first.

Comment: Hello! It looks like your original question was too vague. There is no way to pick a "better" machine translation from the two, they are both worse. I've renamed your question so that it focuses on one objectively asnwerable part. Thanks and welcome to Russian.SE!

Answer (score 2):

*Лодыжка* and *щиколотка* are synonyms in everyday speech, they both mean "ankle".

Some people use the word *лодыжка* for the ankle joint in the anatomical sense, and *щиколотка* for the protruding bone which is visible outside. But it's not a common distinction, and most speakers don't really differentiate between the two.

As for the translation, I think you're looking for this:

> Молния со светоотражающей отделкой на щиколотке.

"Detailing" as in "ornamentation or decoration on a piece of clothing" would be *отделка*, not *деталь*.

"Reflective" as in safety feature is better put as *светоотражающий* "light-reflective".

Finally, *со светоотражающей отделкой* is better placed next to the word *молния*. Literally, your original phrase would read as "zips on ankles with reflective detailing", and it's not immediately clear which one has the detailing: the zips or the ankles.

It's obvious from the context of course, but it's stylistically better to avoid this confusion.